# ggplot back-to-back bar charts ignoring factor order

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create back-to-back bar charts long the lines of

[Creating a stacked bar chart centered on zero using ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505889/creating-a-stacked-bar-chart-centered-on-zero-using-ggplot)

However, the ordering of the fill levels in my bars seems to be ignored even though I've specified the fill variable as an ordered factor?

MWE

```
# Illustrate problem with factors being ignored

mydata <- read.csv(textConnection(
"Attribute, Score, Percent
A1, Poor, 10
A1, Below Avg, 20
A1, Above Avg, 20
A1, Excellent, 50
A2, Poor, 20
A2, Below Avg, 20
A2, Above Avg, 20
A2, Excellent, 40"), as.is=TRUE, strip.white=TRUE, header=TRUE)
mydata$Score <- factor(mydata$Score, 
  levels=c('Poor','Below Avg','Above Avg','Excellent'), order=TRUE)
str(mydata)


myplot <- ggplot(data=mydata, aes(x=Attribute))+
  geom_bar(data=subset(mydata, 
       as.character(mydata$Score) %in% c("Poor","Below Avg")), 
       aes(y= -Percent, fill=Score), stat='identity')+
  geom_bar(data=subset(mydata, 
       !as.character(mydata$Score) %in% c("Poor","Below Avg")),  
       aes(y=  Percent, fill=Score), stat='identity')+
geom_hline( yintercept=0, size=2, color="red")+
coord_flip()

myplot
```

gives

Notice the the levels of the fill are sorted alphabetically, rather than according to the ordered factor.

Thanks
Carl Schwarz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been a challenging problem. I have come to a solution, but the truth is I do not understand why reason solves the problem.

```
mydata <- mydata[c(2,1,3,4,6,5,7,8), ]
```

At first I thought the problem was in the transformation factor to character, but the same code that you put works well.

It seems a good idea to change the order of the legend.

```
myplot + scale_fill_discrete(limits=c("Excellent", "Above Avg", "Below Avg","Poor"))
```

Comment: Hmmm... very odd that the data order should affect the result, but your suggestion works...