# Back to back bar chart with three levels: Can I center the plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wish to create a back to back bar chart. In my data, I have a number of species observations (n) from 2017 and 2018. Some species occurred only in 2017 other occurred both years and some only occurred in 2018. I wish to depict this in a graph centered around the number of species occurring both years across multiple sites (a,b,c).

First, I create a data set:

```
n <- sample(1:50, 9)
reg <- c(rep("2017", 3), rep("Both",3), rep("2018", 3))
plot <- c(rep(c("a", "b", "c"), 3))

d4 <- data.frame(n, reg, plot)
```

I use ggplot to try to plot my graph - I have tried two ways:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d4, aes(plot, n, fill = reg)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip()

ggplot(d4, aes(x = plot, y = n, fill = reg))+
  coord_flip()+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.75)
```

I get a plot similar to what I want. However, would like the blue 'both' bar to be in between the 2017 and 2018 bars. Further, my main problem, I would like to center the 'both' bar in the middle of the plot. The 2017 column should extend to the left and the 2018 column to the right. My question is somewhat similar to the one in the link below; however, as I have only three and not four levels in my graph, I cannot use the same approach as below.

[Creating a stacked bar chart centered on zero using ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505889/creating-a-stacked-bar-chart-centered-on-zero-using-ggplot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the best way to do that, but here is a way to do that:

```
library(dplyr)
d4pos <- d4 %>%
    filter(reg != 2018) %>%
    group_by(reg, plot) %>%
    summarise(total = sum(n)) %>% 
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(total = total * ifelse(reg == "Both", .5, 1))
d4neg <- d4 %>%
    filter(reg != 2017) %>%
    group_by(reg, plot) %>%
    summarise(total = - sum(n)) %>% 
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(total = total * ifelse(reg == "Both", .5, 1))

ggplot(data = d4pos, aes(x = plot, y = total, fill = reg)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
    geom_bar(data = d4neg, stat = "identity", aes(x = plot, y = total, fill = reg)) + 
    coord_flip()
```

I generate two data frames for the total of each group. One contains the 2017 and (half of) Both, and the other contains the rest. The value for the 2018 data frame is flipped to plot on the negative side.

The output looks like this:

[image]

**EDIT**
If you want to have positive values in both directions for the horizontal axis, you can do something like this:

```
ggplot(data = d4pos, aes(x = plot, y = total, fill = reg)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
    geom_bar(data = d4neg, stat = "identity", aes(x = plot, y = total, fill = reg)) + 
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-50, 50, by = 25), 
                       labels = abs(seq(-50, 50, by = 25))) +
    coord_flip()
```